# Why doesn't scaffolding work as expected?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to scaffold and I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MvcProduct.Data.MvcProductContext'.'

Here you can see an image of it:
[image: Error when scaffolding]

The following is my **`MvcProductContext`**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcProduct.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MvcProduct.Data
{
    public class MvcProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcProductContext(DbContextOptions<MvcProductContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
```

And the **`appsettings.json`**:

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcProductContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcProductContext-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

**`ConfigureServices`** method in **`Startup.cs`** file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDbContext<MvcProductContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcProductContext")));
}
```

I have also tried to add a a second constructor in **`MvcProductContext`** class. (Something which I would like to avoid and don't want to do) A second contructor without any parameter. But if I do that I just get another error which says:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured bu overriding the `DbContext.OnConfiguring` method or by using `AddDbContext` on the application service provider. If `AddDbContext` on the application service provider. If `AddDbContext` is used, then also ensure that your `DbCotnext` type accepts a `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for `DbContext`.

Microsoft is does the same. They are scaffolding an MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework. They are doing it without adding a second constructor in their **MvcMovieCOntext** class. Their **MvcMovieContextClass** corresponds to my **MvcProductContext** class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need parameter-less constructor.  You also need your application configuration to include a reference to the connection string

Comment: @Glenn Ferrie Okay but why does Microsoft not include a parameter-less constructor in their example? Also when I add a parameterless constructor below the one I already have in the MvcProductContext I get another error which I have put in the post. With regards to including a reference to a connection string I think I am doing that in my startup.cs file in the ConfigureServices method? I have updated the original post with code from my Startup.cs file.

Comment: This looks like it should work, what version of .net core sdk have you installed? (at cmd line run:  dotnet --info). Is that the same version as used in the Microsoft example?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem.It only appears when your forget to register the dbcontext but you have added it from your code.Could you try it in a brand new mvc project?

Comment: @Andrew I have Version:   3.0.100. In visual studio 2019 I selected 3.0 as the project version and I selected the Microsoft guide to 3.0 as well.

Comment: @Xing Zou Yes we will try that out now.

Comment: Thankyou. We tried it out with a brand new Mvc project and it worked. One of the changes we made this time is that we used ASP.NET Core 2.2 instead of 3.0. This time we set the Data Context Class to MvcProduct.Models.MvcProductContext when we were scaffolding just as it is in the Microsoft Documentation. In the 3.0 Documentation from Microsoft it said that the Data Context Class should be changed to MvcProduct.Data.MvcProductContext. Perhaps that was what made the difference.Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In **.net core 6** :

- Install 4 packages:

1.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

2.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

3.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

4.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

- Scaffold the data base and create the DbContext and Entities by scaffold command or ef core power tools vs extension.
- Inject your data base settings in program.cs :

  builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

  ```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CS"));
    });
  ```
- Add your connection string to appsettings.json :

  {
  "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "CS": "Server=.\SQLExpress2022;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1) implementation to your project and try scaffolding again. It will take care of instantiating your DbContext.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MvcProductContext>
{
    public MvcProductContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MvcProductContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcProductContext");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new MvcProductContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```